# UTF8 Character Encoding Error

Tags: mongodb, powershell, unicode

I'm currently outputting a long string through powershell as unicode using the below syntax ([reference for doing it this way](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849882.aspx)):

```
$string | out-file $path -encoding unicode
```

If I try to import this file in mongo, or another process that can't read UTF8 characters, I get an "Invalid UTF8 character detected."  Is this the incorrect syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unicode is not the same encoding as Utf8. Have you tried -encoding ASCII or -encoding Utf8?

Comment: Huge thanks, Keith!  I misread the error - it was the inverse of what I was thinking it was.  Thanks again.